# How do I setup the SFML library in Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, sfml, clion

I am using the CLion IDE on linux which mandates developing using cmake. I have followed [this](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-linux.php) to get the following pieces of code.

I have the following sample code :

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My CMakeLists.txt is as follows :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(SFML_codes)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SFML_INCLUDE_DIR "/home/user/Desktop/SFML-2.5.0/include")
set(SFML_LIBRARY_DIR "/home/user/Desktop/SFML-2.5.0/lib")
link_directories("/home/user/Desktop/SFML-2.5.0/lib")
include_directories("/home/user/Desktop/SFML-2.5.0/include")
set(SFML_DIR "/home/user/Desktop/SFML-2.5.0/lib/cmake/SFML")
find_package(SFML 2.5.0 COMPONENTS system window graphics network audio)

if(SFML_FOUND)

    message(STATUS "SFML_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    message(STATUS "SFML_LIBRARIES: ${SFML_LIBRARIES}")
    message(STATUS "SFML_VERSION: ${SFML_VERSION}")

    include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIRS})

endif()
add_executable(SFML_codes main.cpp)

target_link_libraries (SFML_codes sfml-graphics sfml-window sfml-system)
```

Output :

```
free(): invalid pointer

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

After a lot of struggle to eliminate linker errors, I am able to compile successfully. But on running the code I got an error which is trying to free/delete something which isn't a pointer. I debugged a little and it appears to be the first line in main method which cause this error. As per the link above it is supposed to run fine.

To my surprise, the following code ran fine :

```
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    sf::Clock Clock;
    while (Clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() < 5.f)
    {
        std::cout << Clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() << std::endl;
        sf::seconds(0.5f);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "it appears to be the first line in main method which cause this error" - the `sf::RenderWindow` line? Can you step into the SFML code to see what's going wrong? It's probably worth trying the g++ link line from the tutorial exactly as-is to see if that works too.

Comment: So the constructor is `RenderWindow(VideoMode mode, const String& title, Uint32 style = Style::Default, const ContextSettings& settings = ContextSettings())` which calls `ContextSettings()` which is `explicit ContextSettings(unsigned int depth = 0, unsigned int stencil = 0, unsigned int antialiasing = 0, unsigned int major = 1, unsigned int minor = 1, unsigned int attributes = Default, bool sRgb = false)`. Apparently it initialises a few values in a struct but I don't know why it would give a pointer error.  File: https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/include/SFML/Window/ContextSettings.hpp

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code from what I can see. Try to get a stacktrace to see where it fails (obviously some static object's constructor).

Comment: You should also add `-Wl,-R,/home/user/Desktop/SFML-2.5.0/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags` to your `LDFLAGS` to ensure the library you compile and link against is the same one you use at runtime.

Comment: Is there any CMakeLists.txt equivalent for those flags?

Comment: Strange thing is, when I run it in gdb and step through, at `    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
` it tells me that `/usr/local/share/buildslave/debian-gcc-64/build/src/SFML/Window/VideoMode.cpp: No such file or directory`. Why is it looking at a location different than what is mentioned in the cmake file?

Comment: More info : stepping through the code, it keeps looking for files which do not exist. Like `/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/basic_string.h: No such file or directory.` . I am using g++ 7.3.0 . Can this be an issue?